# dotnetopenauth Realm protocol exception

Tags: exception, dotnetopenauth

Using dotnetopenauth, my code worked fine when using `openId.CreateRequest(openIdIdentifier)`. The return url was /default.aspx which i didnt want so to specify the return_to param i had to fill in realm. The desc of the 2nd param is

```
    //   realm:
    //     The shorest URL that describes this relying party web site's address.  For
    //     example, if your login page is found at https://www.example.com/login.aspx,
    //     your realm would typically be https://www.example.com/.
```

So logically the correct code is

```
var request = openId.CreateRequest(openIdIdentifier, new Uri("http://localdev.com:8844/"), new Uri("http://localdev.com:8844/login"));
```

However i get this ProtocolException

> The openid.return_to parameter
>   (http://localdev.com:8844/login?dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=http://myid.myopenid.com/)
>   does not match the actual URL
>   (http://localdev.com:8844/Default.aspx?dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=http://myid.myopenid.com/&openid.assoc_handle=...)
>   the request was made with.

WTF

How do i return to /login without an exception? and bonus points if you can tell me how to have it use POST instead of GET

Comment: Probably, it's a little bit late, but looks like /default.aspx is invoked from default sample code: case response.Status == Authenticated then "FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you get this error after the OpenID Provider appears on the browser, and during the redirect back to the RP, is that right?

It looks like the Provider you're testing with is sending the browser to the wrong URL.  But since it's very unlikely for a Provider to manufacture "default.aspx" out of nowhere, we need to look at the logs to find out exactly what's going on.

You can [obtain logs locally by following these instructions](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/loggingdebugging-dotnetopenauth-with-log4net/).
or by trying to log into your own RP site with this OpenID identifier: http://test-id.org/RP/POSTAssertion.aspx  This is a diagnostic identifier that will produce log messages at http://test-id.org/TracePage.aspx.  Either way you collect them, please add the relevant logs to your question so we can better analyze what's going on.

Comment: I think you may have misread something. I suspect if no return url is given it redirects to / which ASP.NET will change to default.aspx. Thus why i am using the overload with realm and returnToUrl. The realm  is what is giving me the problem -edit- but now the page does return to /login like i wanted. I just get an exception thrown which is very annoying and makes no sense

Comment: Actually on another look it seems like dotnetopenauth specifies it as i see default aspx in the GET request to myopenid.

Comment: Why do you insist that realm is what is giving you the problem?  According to the error you included in your question, this has nothing to do with realm.  The value DotNetOpenAuth specified/sees in the `openid.return_to` parameter doesn't match the URL that is actually processing the positive assertion from the Provider.  In case you don't know, the OpenID return_to parameter is entirely different from the ASP.NET forms auth ReturnUrl parameter.

Comment: I'm quite confused. I can tell you if i dont specify the realm and return_to it works. I cant imagine a return to url being 'wrong' (assuming its your site and a valid uri). What does DotNetOpenAuth  think is the 'URL that is actually processing the positive assertion from the Provider'? You mention 'manufacture "default.aspx" out of nowhere'. I dont see default being in the GET request of anything. (Either there or back) I am not sure why dotnetopenauth thinks default the login page.

Comment: As a workaround i just moved my login code to default and have it redirect to login if there is an error. Its just annoying/frustrating i cant specify the return to location without problems.

Comment: The URL that you specify to `OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest` as the return_to URL must be a web page that calls `OpenIdRelyingParty.GetResponse`.  Typically that is also the login page, and once the login page processes the response and finds it acceptable it sets the FormsAuth cookie and redirects the user at the same time using `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage`.  This redirect goes to wherever `ReturnUrl` says and doesn't have to be anything special.  But if `ReturnUrl` is not specified, ASP.NET redirects the user to '/', or wherever the web.config file says to.

Comment: `once the login page processes the response`. Ok in my code the login page (/login) calls OpenIdRelyingParty.GetResponse() and if its null it calls OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest. The return to is set to login so when it replies it should still call OpenIdRelyingParty.GetResponse then OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest is resp is null. But here is the problem. As you said `once the login page processes the response`. It cant. i get the protocol exception mention in my question. http://www.pastie.org/1394032

Comment: Thanks for the pastie snippet, but I'm confused at what I'm seeing.  It doesn't look like ASP.NET web forms *or* MVC.  What am I looking at?  Also, it looks fishy that you have if-checks for parameters in all your methods as if you don't know what's coming in.  Typically either you have dedicated URLs for steps in the flow or DotNetOpenAuth can detect it for you.

Comment: Its asp.net but not a webform. Its a hacky way i very much enjoy. I basically have one line in my default.aspx and it calls all the code it needs to generate the html. Anyways... wait it just hit me, it might be because i dont use it as the traditional webform way. In global.apax i rewrite every thing via context.RewritePath("/Default.aspx"); (except files but i wont get into that). in default.aspx i write `<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableSessionState="False"%><% prjname.PageRequest.WritePage();%>`. Then from there i get uri AbsolutePath and pass it through regex to deduce which page is requested

Comment: On (almost) all pages i create a BasicUser object and write baseuser.ShowPageName(sometimes_with_params). It has helper members to generate html, connection to db (if i need it etc). This class is where i call root and login page and this is why req (HttpRequest) is a member function. Now that i think of it i can see it pulling up /default.aspx on my login page because ALL pages are through /default.aspx. But then again shouldnt it also think i am on the correct page... Maybe its using something like FilePath or Path on one page and RawUrl on another? BTW i need a @acid for a ping/the light.

Comment: Last thing. Before you try fixing anything i want to mention I may not use it since my server has a 90% likely chance of being linux. It tried and it doesnt appear to work on mono and i know mono has https/SSL issues.

Comment: If you're playing URL rewrite tricks, that sounds like it is very likely the problem.  DotNetOpenAuth allows you to work with that anyway by calling the overloads of methods on `OpenIdRelyingParty` that take an `HttpRequestInfo` object that you've programmed in with the correct URLs instead of the ones DNOA auto-detects.

Comment: As far as whether you work on Linux or not, there is a mono2 branch of DNOA that *does* work on Linux, but it is much less supported than the Windows version.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue today, though I'm using pure MVC3. At least with MVC, there is no need to send returnUrl over with `CreateRequest()`, it seems to be enough just pass returnUrl as parameter when posting form to your login handler, something like this:

View:

```
<form action="/Login/LogOn?returnUrl=@returnUrl" method="post">
```

Controller:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult LogOn(string returnUrl)
{...}
```

Interestingly, returnUrl variable is then still available, even during second pass thru this method during OpenID authentication, when `RelyingParty.GetResponse()` is no longer null.

Comment: I didnt but i can tell you what caused it. I had ALL my urls rewrote to default.aspx which then calls the backend for the html. This is why it expected default and didnt allow login. You can call the overloads of methods on `OpenIdRelyingParty` that take an `HttpRequestInfo` but i never did figure that out bc i was lazy and i had to get it working under linux but test under windows so i figure it was a bad idea to bother and stopped trying.